# ordering ng-repeat by several properties

Tags: angularjs, variables, filter, properties, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table to indicate results of certain teams, each team has two values - PTS (points) and GD (goal difference).

Data looks something like this:

```
A: PTS=3, GD=+3,
B: PTS=2, GD=+1,
C: PTS=2, GD=-1,
D: PTS=0, GD=-1
```

I want display them via ng-repeat, in order of PTS first and foremost (as above). But if any team is equal with another on points, it will need to be decided by GD (goal difference). Finally if even this another sort them, I want it to fall back to alphabetical ordering.

I know how to use orderBy, and then can just use the `teamName` propery (A, B, C) etc. to order them.

I am guessing it is something like creating a custom orderBy filter something like this:

```
orderBy="{{pts || gd || teamName}}"
```

I'm not sure of the syntax though, or where to put this code. Can I attach the above logic to one variable and then call that in orderBy? Or is it a filter?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

To use orderBy with multiple fields, you have to add this fields in array like ['pst', 'gd', 'teamName']

Now data is:

```
      A: PTS=3, GD=+3,
      B: PTS=2, GD=+1,
      C: PTS=2, GD=-1,
      D: PTS=0, GD=-1
```

if consider "A", "B", "C" & "D" are team names.

- teamName -> **ascending** order
- gd -> **ascending** order
- pts -> **descending** order

then orderBy syntax is :

```
        orderBy:['-pst', 'gd', 'teamName']
```

*** "-pst" is used to display pst elements in descending order